# Looking for a better solution: preloading sounds into memory

Tags: ios, swift

So when an application play a sound for the first time a little lag occurs.
I've looked for a solution to this issue. The only one I've found recommends playing a sound somewhere in the beginning to let it load to memory.

I am wondering if there is another way. Or I have to play them all in some scene after loading my app? And if I play them together at once its gonna sound weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` to preload a sound into memory without playing it.

Check out Jacob Van Order's [Sound Machine](https://github.com/jacobvanorder/SoundMachine) which has a nice Obj-C wrapper around the sound functions you're likely to use. It preloads all of the sounds into memory and makes it as easy to use as `UIImage`:

```
[[SGSoundMachine soundMachine] playSoundWithName:@"fileName"]
```

I haven't tried it in a Swift project, but I think it should bridge without much difficulty.